# XPages retrieve current logged on Active Directory User

Tags: active-directory, xpages

Can anyone advise how I might be able to retrieve the current logged on Active Directory user?

I have been looking through how this would normally be done in JSF:

```
javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest().getUserPrincipal()
```

Unfortunately this always seems to retrieve the domino user.

Comment: Could you describe your environment a little more? Are you using SPENGO for authentication?

Comment: Does @Username not work?

Comment: SPENGO is a pest. Have a look at Puakma SSO instead: http://www.puakma.net/puakma/website.pma/BoosterESSO

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "Active Directory User". When you authenticate with a Domino server you always get a "Domino user" regardless of what you authenticated your user against. I would suspect that the AD is delivering a "Domino user" name on authentication which can look different from the AD credentials depending on your configuration.
So your course of action would then be a LDAP lookup into AD to get the matching AD user.

Comment: Let me explain reasons for looking into this. At present we have users that may have notes accounts but not active directory or the person documents are not linked to AD; therefore they may access the database but are unable to use authenticate. The result of this a HTTP 403 Forbidden error rather than asking them to login manually.
So what i have been looking to do is get the current logged in AD user the manually lookup that user in domino NAB and log the person in on that account using the code here from Serdar Basegmez on XSnippets.

Comment: Ahhh... the awfully sounds like a code band-aid for an infrastructure short coming. They never work. The whole point of an application server (be it Domino, WAS, JBoss, Tomcat or others) is abstraction. SO the appServer logs you in and THAT identity is all the application is allowed to deal with. SO your users are logged in (@UserName doesn't return "Anonymous") but fail at the ACL? The short fix is to alter the ACL, the right thing to do is to sort out the AD link (TDI anyone). Don't try to fix infrastructure in code. But if you have to: LDAP is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the LDAP distinguishedName attribute as Domino suggests you may be able to get an LDAP authenticated user's name using a formula like this:

```
@If(
 @NameLookup([NoUpdate]:[NoSearching]; @UserName ;"Fullname")!=""; @Name([CN];@UserName);
 @NameLookup([NoUpdate]:[TrustedOnly]; @UserName; "cn")=@Name([CN];@UserName);  @NameLookup( [NoUpdate]:[TrustedOnly]; @UserName ;"displayName");
 @UserName );
```

But in Xpages I think you'll need to use Java to do an LDAP lookup.